Angular conditional coverage inside ngAfterViewInit
I have a code under ngAfterViewInit unable to coverage conditions/branches
As i need to cover 100% on new code, please give me suggestions (currently at 68%)

Tried few tests but not covering branches


please share code instead of screenshots!

We need to mock the observable as of({...}), then we can call ngAfterViewInit which will attach the rest of the pipes to the observable, after the method runs, we subscribe and get the output, notice I use fakeAsync and flush to wait for the API to complete to evaluate the results, I hope you get the approach the solve this! do let me know if any doubts!
describe('ngAfterViewInit', () => {
    const data = {
        fund: {
          entity: [
            {
              profile: {
                ticker: 'VGRLX'
              },
              fees: {
                redemptionFee: {
                  content: null,
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      };
    beforeEach(() => {
      component.data$ = of(data) as any;
    });

    it('should set the fund fess to 0.25%', fakeAsync(() => {
      component.ngAfterViewInit();
      let output = null;
      component.data$.subscribe((response: any) => output = response);
      flush();
      expect(output.fund.entity[0].fees.redemptionFee.content).toEqual("0.25%");
    }));

    it('should not set the fund fess to 0.25%', fakeAsync(() => {
      data.fund.entity[0].profile.ticker = 'asdf'; // <- typo
      component.ngAfterViewInit();
      let output = null;
      component.data$.subscribe((response: any) => output = response);
      flush();
      expect(output.fund.entity[0].fees.redemptionFee.content).toBeNull();
    }));
  });


unable to cover all the branches/conditions.
inorderto increase coverage need to cover all the branches
data.fund?.entity?.forEach(fund => {
if(redemptionFeeTickers.has(fund.profile.ticker)) {
fund.fees.redemptionFee.content = "0.25%"
}
})
@Naren Murali, please give some idea ..

@Developer there was a typo, try now! I already covered the branches!

@Murali can you suggest how to coverage all the conditions ? (those three lines showing red not covered)

@Developer we need to run ngAfterViewInit then subscribe to data$, then for loop will run and get covered. Is my code not working!

@Murali will check the coverage

@Murali thanks lot test case covered the code
